# how to solve problem with Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array react/jsx-key when I map react-icons?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-icons

I tried many methods to display dynamically Icons,but this one work in my case:

```
   <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row"}}>
   {logo?.map((logos, index )=> {return (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
    <IconContext.Provider
    key={index}
      value={{ color: "#fff", size: '30px', display: "inlineblock"}}
    >
      <div>
{logos}
</div>
    </IconContext.Provider>
    </React.Fragment>
   )})     }</div>
```

I have this (in future I want it fetch from database) in const:

```
const realizacjeGallery = [{
  id: "ssss",
  title: "ssss", 
  description: <>zzxxx</>,
  photo: zzz,
  logo: [<DiReact/>, <SiFirebase/>]
},
{ id: "ss",
  title: "ssss",
description: <>zzz
</>,
photo: zzz,
logo: [<DiReact/>, <SiFirebase/>]

}, 
{
  id: "zzz",
  title: "sssl",
description: <>ssss
</>,
photo: muz,
logo: [<BsWordpress/>, <DiJqueryLogo/>]

}

]
```

and this piece of code display on frond-end my icons. But after deployment, I get an fatal error:

```
Error: Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
```

and I do not have any clue what more I should do. I tried many combinations of key like `` key={`${title}` + index} `` but it do not change anything.

Comment: You're also missing a `key` prop in each logo that you render in `{logos}`. `logos` is an array of JSX elements, so each of its items need to have a `key` prop, i.e. `[<DiReact key="react" />, <SiFirebase key="firebase" />]`.

Comment: Solved it the easiest way I know just change array of items to array of objects: ``` logo: [{id: "eact1", logo: <DiReact>} ()...] ```

Answer (score 0):

In react, index should be the last thing to pass as Key you can use title or unique ID as key.
you can read more [here](https://reactpatterns.js.org/docs/indexes-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/#:%7E:text=Keys%20should%20be%20unique%20so,render%20a%20list%20as%20below.&text=A%20key%20is%20the%20only%20thing%20React%20uses%20to%20identify%20DOM%20elements.)

[More](https://medium.com/geekculture/reactjs-why-index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-4b9dc6ef0067)